# How to specify Custom Checkpoint for Spring Cloud Stream Binder Azure Event Hub?

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-eventhub

I'm following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub) on how to integrate Spring with Azure Event Hubs.
In the article, it uses Azure Storage to store the event hub checkpoints. Is there a way to customize it and use another storage (e.g. db, redis)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Spring Cloud SDK is tightly coupled specifically with **Azure Storage Blob** as Event Hub checkpoint store.

However in regular Java SDK, you have the option of overriding abstract CheckpointStore class to something custom as per your need and plugin to [EventProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable#consume-events-using-an-event-processor-client) (like the default [BlobCheckpointStore](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob/src/main/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/checkpointstore/blob/BlobCheckpointStore.java) implements it)